# Dropping PendingIntents

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Is it ok to drop PendingIntents in android if they are never used. Such as in an AppWidgetProvider where a PendingIntent that was never used be overwritten by a new PendingIntent.

Or should we call cancel on all unused PendingIntents to clean up memory appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call cancel.